# Browser is still looking for an old favicon even with a new one in place?

Tags: html, asp.net, favicon, master-pages

I've ran into an odd problem with an ASP.Net website and the favicon.  Recently, the favicon was changed to a new file called favicon2 and in the site master the line got changed from this...

```
 <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/ico"/>
```

to this in *site.master* ...

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon2.ico" type="image/ico"/>
```

Everything worked fine until a week later in Chrome the developer console started complaining about below error:

> "failed to load resource: the server responded with a 404 (Not Found)"

that involving the *favicon.ico*.  There's literally no reference to the file in the code base and this is purely showing up in IE, Chrome, etc.  In the meantime the new favicon icon is still loading fine.

Any idea on what is going on with this?

Comment: This is because all modern browsers by default will always make a request for a file specifically named `favicon.ico`, and since you do not have that exact file name you will get a 404 error. If you dont use that exact name you might have to clear Chromes favicon cache and / or all cache using the "All Time" option when clearing browsing history. But then other users might have to do the same, so its best to just name it `favicon.ico` which is what the browser is trying to request from the server.

Comment: Ah okay, I was not even aware of that.  I don't think anyone is going to mind having the icon renamed to the old name.  I'll just have to add the syntax to indicate it's the 2nd version.